# Why won't the form values stay when you hit back?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have 2 forms, one is the initial registration (member) and the other is for outsiders posting.

Both go to a confirmation page of information and both have error checking in PHP. If you submit and you're missing a field and hit BACK, the values in the first form are saved... although the values in the second form are lost.

Is there a specific validation of sorts, I double checked DOCTYPES etc.

Any idea as to what causes this to work/not work?

**EDIT: Fixed, making sure all ELEMENT tags were properly opened/closed/positioned as well as DOCTYPES made the information return when failing to validate.**

Comment: Usualy this is related to dinamically generated form fields.

Comment: If I post all my code, you'll be reading for quite a long while.. I'll give you the important elements.. Updating.

Comment: and @user1394965 I wasn't looking for code specific-answers. I was wondering if anyone was aware of a specific method or requirements that 'activate' this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had this issue before, you have to make sure that ALL your HTML Elements are properly closed. For example,  (Add the slash at the end), for 
 etc.. make sure DIVs are opened and closed without overlapping into other DIVs and this should solve the problem.

Nothing too crazy

Comment: This is what I was wondering!! Thank you, I'll double-check and get back to you.

Comment: I found a few tags that were opened and closed oddly and it worked. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This could be browser related. Normally the browser will keep the form's data when you go back. But if you submit another form, that data is lost.
The only way would be to submit both forms every time or to use javascript and keep data in a php session.

Using jquery (for example), you would say that everytime an input was changed, the whole form is sent to the PHP session using AJAX. When you load your form, you then load the values from the session global var.

```
$('#myform input').change(function(){
    var formdata = $('form#myform').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process.php",
        data: formdata
    }).done(function( msg ) {
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    });
});
```

And on the php side:

```
$_SESSION['form_cache']['form_name'] = parse_str($_POST['data']);
```

Then when you load your form

```
<?php
$test = isset($_SESSION['form_cache']['form_name']['test']) ? $_SESSION['form_cache']['form_name']['test'] : '';
?>
<input type="text" name="test" value="<?=$test?>" />
```